# Problem with central limit theory

Tags: probability

I understand a proof of CLT and I'm using it frequantly, but just realised, that I dont understand one thing - how is it possibile that mean from uniform distribution can have Normal distribution? My problem od that mean from uniform is strictly limited, and cant exced given value, where in normal distribution you can have values form (-inf to inf). I hope I formulated the problem clearly :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the theorem is called the "central limit theorem" is that it describes the functional form of the **center** (middle) of the distribution. It really has nothing to say about the tails (something that is frequently misunderstood).